# passing data between controllers

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to transfer a URL from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`, but for some reason the image does not get displayed in `UIImageView` from the submitted URL. Here is my code:

**TableView.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *url = @"http://www.macdigger.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Apple-Nokia-Samsung-1.jpg";

    ImageViewController *imageView = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];        
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"imageViewController"] animated:YES];

    [imageView setDetailItem:url];

}
```

**ImageViewController.m**

```
@interface ImageViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation ImageViewController

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newUrl
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newUrl);
    self.urlOfImage = newUrl;
    [self configureView];

}

- (void)configureView
{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlOfImage];
        NSLog(@"%@",url); //There URL is normally displayed in the log
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        _imageView.image = image;//And then the picture does not want to output
}
```

In the logs passed URL is displayed (where bold). It turns out that the URL itself is passed, but `UIImageView`, does not display image from this URL.

P.P.S. **Data** displays at the logs in the form of `"<ffd8ffe1 00184578 69660000 49492a00 08000000 00000000 00000000 ffec0011 4475636b 79000100 04000000 460000ff e1031b68 7474703a 2f2f6e73 2e61646f 62652e63 6f6d2f78 61702f31 2e302f00 3c3f7870 61636b65 74206265 67696e3d 22efbbbf 22206964...>"`

Comment: have you linked/connected imageView ?

Comment: try nslogging just above _imageView.image.....  is it printing some numbers or null/nill ?

Comment: @AKV  Data displays at the logs in the form of "<ffd8ffe1 00184578 69660000 49492a00 08000000 00000000 00000000 ffec0011 4475636b 79000100 04000000 460000ff e1031b68 7474703a 2f2f6e73 2e61646f 62652e63 6f6d2f78 61702f31 2e302f00 3c3f7870 61636b65 74206265 67696e3d 22efbbbf 22206964...>"

Comment: is there reason why you add controller to navigation controller manually, instead of using performSegue and prepareForSegue?

Comment: @Mikhail Because I use custom cells that are called from .xib

Comment: Using custom cells is no real reason for not segueing. However, it should not matter much that you do this programmatically. My question/hint: did you try calling setNeedsDisplay?

Comment: @Mikhail Thank you very much for your help. I decided to remove it all and make a seque ... this helped.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thank you very much for your help. I decided to remove it all and make a seque ... this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be error because ViewController is not loaded yet, try to check whether it already loaded in `setDetailItem` method, if it not loaded - configureView in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newUrl
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newUrl);
    self.urlOfImage = newUrl;
    if ([self isViewLoaded]) {
        [self configureView];
    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.urlOfImage) {
        [self configureView]
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not help(( I do not understand why the picture is downloaded from the transmitted URL ("data" is displayed), but will not be published!

Comment: Try to check in your configure view whether _imageView != nil, if so - check your IBOutlets, or where you create it

Comment: If Mikhail is right, which could well be, then your configureView is called before the view is finally loaded. If that is the case then loading the view from NIB (or while executing loadView respectively) will clear the contents of the _imageView. Furthermore _imageView will be allocated for the first time then. The strange thing with obj-c is that `_imageView.image = image;` will execute nicley when _imageView is nil. But of course it does not display anything.

Comment: @Mikhail I checked - _imageView.image = nil

Comment: @HermannKlecker Sorry, but I did not understand a bit what you had in mind (not quite understand English). What should I do?

Comment: If you make all accordingly to my advise, method configureView should be loaded after viewDidLoad (check if it so by doing some logging), when all .xib already loaded and outlets connected. If sequence of method calls is Ok - check whether _imageView is connected from xib (or created previously).

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just make another initializer?

```
ImageViewController *imageView = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithURL:urlToGo];
```

in .m file, on top:

```
@interface ImageViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;
@end

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *url){
   self = /* any kind of normal initialization, xib or storyboard */ [super init];
   if (self) {
       _url = url;
   }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self configureView];
}
```